# Passing express instance and route separation on two server files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a middleware to run two server files with same instance and trying to separate the routes. I will try to explain it the best way with examples:

Folder Structure:

```
/common-server
   /routers
     /routes.js
   /app1
     /server.js
     /index.html
   /app2
     /server2.js
     /index2.html
   /app.js
   /package.json
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app       = express();
const routes    = require('./routers/routes');
PORT = 8005;

app.set('express', app);
app.use('/internal', routes);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`Application is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here I am setting the express app instance to use the same on other server files.

routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/app1", (req, res) => {
    let appInstance = req.app.get('express');
    require('../app1/server')(appInstance);
});

router.get("/app2", (req, res) => {
    let appInstance = req.app.get('express');
    require('../app2/server2')(appInstance);
});

module.exports = router;
```

inside /app1/server I am just trying to send the html which belongs to this app and same goes for app2.

```
const path = require("path");
const staticDir = path.join(__dirname);

module.exports = function (server) {
  server.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(staticDir, "index.html")));
};
```

The app seems to work fine for only one route which is http://localhost:8005/internal/app1 but when I am trying to switch between routes not getting any response from http://localhost:8005/internal/app2 and the page is getting loading endlessly.

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
router.get("/app1", (req, res) => {
    let route = req.app.get('express');
    require('../app1/server')(route);
});
```

Can never work.  What this is doing is when you get a `/app1` incoming request, you're then registering another route handler, but not actually doing anything with the current request.  You should be registering routes, once and only once.  Then Express will match those routes and call the associated route handler.

If you just want to move route handlers to other files, then you can just make them regular functions and export them and then call them.

```
const { handler1 } = require('../app1/server');

router.get("/app1", (req, res) => {
    handler1(req, res);
});
```

Or, you can even just do this:

```
const { handler1 } = require('../app1/server');

router.get("/app1", handler1);
```

Then, inside of `../app1/server`:

```
const path = require("path");
const staticDir = path.join(__dirname);

module.exports.handler1 = function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(staticDir, "index.html"));
};
```

Comment: I think you got confused with the name route in the above /app/server file, I have updated the same to get a better understanding. It's not a route but an appInstance that is passed to the server file when /app1 is called.

Comment: @Vish - What do you think I got confused about?  You're calling `app.get()` inside another `app.get()`.  That can NEVER work.  All you do is register another route inside an existing route.  That just reregisters the same route over and over again and never even sends a response to the first route.  That's just wrong coding - Express doesn't work that way.  And, please don't ever say your code is "just an example", therefore I shouldn't look at it.  Your question needs to contain code that ACCURATELY represents the problem you are asking about.  If it's not doing that, then fix your question.

Comment: @Vish - Perhaps you don't understand what your code is doing.  When you get a `/app1` request, you get the `appInstance` and pass it to your `/app1/server` module.  And, all that does is then call `appInstance.get(...)` which just registers another route handler.  You NEVER send any response from the `/app1` route.  Further, when you get the second `/app1` request, you do the same thing again, registering a duplicate handler over and over and never sending a response.  Calling `app.get()` just registers a route, it doesn't actually run that route handler.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I understood the problem.